# How do I get the Id of a button of a jquery UI dialog?

Tags: jquery-ui, selenium

as the title says....

this is what I have tried but not working

```
 $('#uxReferralAssessmentDetailsDialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 400,
            title: "Referral Assessment",
            buttons: { "Save":{ id: 'uxbtnSaveAssessment', click:othis.OnAssessmentSave}, "Cancel": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
        });
```

I am using selenium and instead of the horrid xpath I want to use the id of each element to simplify the xpath

any ideas welcome

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a hard time determining id as and other things that are being added to the html page by javascript on the fly. Try using a development tool for web browsers like firebug which is an addon for firefox:

See link for firebug addon for more information:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843